# Sorting a array of characters

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

There is a array of 100 blocks, here each block contains one color and this color comes from an array of characters a,b,c,...,z randomly.

Ex:
a b d e g i h f d a

Now you have to write a program, that will return sorted array with following conditions.

1. Following swapping order should be follow.

Character                              maximum swap

a                                                            1

b                                                            2

c                                                            3

...                                                             ...

z                                                             26

Output:
a a b d d e f h g i

I have used the following methods.

//return no of blocks

int getNoOfBlocks();

//return the alphabet at particular block

char getData(int);

//swap the value

void swapBlock(int, int);

void arrangeBlocks(void)

{

int size = getNoOfBlocks();

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)

    {

        int min = getData(i)-97;

        int pos = 0;

        int ascii = 0;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)

            {

               ascii = getData(j)-97;

                if(min > ascii)

                  {

                      min = ascii;

                      pos = j;

                  }

            }

        swapBlock(i, pos+1);

    }
```

}

Comment: go do your homework yourself...

Comment: This question is based on the maximum swap, which is different from other type of sorting mechanism.

Comment: yes and? do you want someone to write the program for you? You can ask a specific question, then you may get an answer

Comment: No I have written my program which i am going to post it here, please review it

Comment: void arrangeBlocks(void)

Comment: not in the comment area, just edit your question

Comment: I have edited and written the program

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: This is not giving me proper output, do i missing somewhere

Comment: are you swapping the right elements? swapBlock(i, pos+1); also your first for loop should be < size -1 I think

Comment: Yes what i'm doing is, currently i = 0, pos+1 = 0

Comment: shouldnt it be swapBlock(i, pos); ?

Comment: i have added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are swapping the wrong elements, it should be:

```
  swapBlock(i, pos);
```

Also your first loop is wrong, it should be:

```
  for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++)
```